# After running the 'expo eject' only the android package shows up. Is there any way I can get the ios folders like a regular react native project?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

A regular React Native app would have the android and ios folders but when I detach expo using `expo eject` only the android package shows up

Comment: you should eject on a macos machine. you can run the command again on macos after you've already ejected

Comment: thanks i will try that

Answer (score 0):

if you are using windows, **expo eject** won't generate ios folder.if you are using macos you can try **expo run:ios**.